# railsの本番環境で、sassを更新するたびに前回のsassに上書きされてしまいます。railsの本番環境AWS sass css config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css, aws, sass

railsのwebサイトをAWS,nginx,unicornを使って、運営しています。
railsの本番環境に新しく、更新したsassを反映をさせようと思って、precompileして再起動するのですが、毎回、前回までの古いsassの上に上書きされる形で反映されてしまい、お互いの反映がぶつかり合ってしまいます。
結果として、新しい変更の方は無視されて、古いsassの方が反映されてしまいます。
おそらく、assets cleanをやってもうまく行かないので、おそらくconfig/environmentのstaging.rb,product.rbが原因だと思うのですが、なかなかあたりがつきません。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/112765

Comment: 推測ではなくて、行った手順とその結果表示などを併記したほうが、回答を得られる確度が高くなると思いますよ。